# Extract paleoclimate variables from wordclim

Tags: raster, r, layers, rasterstack

I1m relative new in to RStudio and I'm trying to download the paleoclimate variables (http://ww.worldclim.com/paleo-climate1) from worldclim, but I can't, the unique solution that I found was to download all the rasters on a folder and to tell rstudio the folder that contains the files. I tried with the common comands for getdata from raster package:

```
getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10)
```

But I need specific scenarios and models (eg. LGM from CCSM4) but the details of that comand explains that not have more arguments apart of variable and resolution:

if name='worldclim' you must also provide arguments var, and a resolution res. Valid variables names are 'tmin', 'tmax', 'prec' and 'bio'. Valid resolutions are 0.5, 2.5, 5, and 10 (minutes of a degree). In the case of res=0.5, you must also provide a lon and lat argument for a tile; for the lower resolutions global data will be downloaded. In all cases there are 12 (monthly) files for each variable except for 'bio' which contains 19 files.

```
getData('worldclim', var='tmin', res=0.5, lon=5, lat=45)
getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10)
```